# The First 8 Square Numbers by using loop in Oracle?

Tags: oracle

How to compute The First 8 Square Numbers by using  loop in Oracle?

```
declare
    total integer;
    i integer;
    begin
    total := 0;
    i := 1;
    loop
    total := total *i;
    i := i*total;
    exit when i > 8;
    end loop;
    dbms_output.put_line('the total is ' || total); end;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What have you already tried yourself to find the problem? Questions should show **evidence of research and attempts to solve the problem yourself**, a clear outline of your specific coding-related issue, and any relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so we have enough information to be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Please examine carefully this fragment:

```
i := 1;
loop
   total := total *i;
   i := i*total;
   exit when i > 8;
end loop;
```

There is `exit when i > 8;` command that is supposed to exit the loop when `i` is greater than 8, but `i` is always 1 within the loop, so the loop is infinite and you never get any result.
You must increment `i` somwhere in the loop using `i := i + 1;` instruction.

Comment: first **8** square numbers, why 100? Also, one could probably assume this is homework in a PL/SQL class, so plain SQL solutions won't help much.

Comment: @muthguy yes, you are right, thank you for comment, I've corrected my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is **not** for your homework, but provides a *solution* for the question.

```
SELECT LEVEL * LEVEL squares
      FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 8;
```

**Output**:

```
1
4
9
16
25
36
49
64
```